# Some questions about Cassandra where clause

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I am reading [A deep look at the CQL WHERE clause](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause). I am confused by several statements, so I posted 5 questions (Q1 - Q5). Any comments welcomed.
Thanks

> Q1: What does `Secondary index queries` mean? What does `the query is using a secondary index` mean?
>
> I think `secondary index queries`==`the query which is using a secondary index`.
>
> But `Secondary index queries` means queries on the table where secondary index exists
>   OR the queried columns are all indexed OR at least one column among
>   all queried columns is indexed?

Single column slice restrictions are allowed only on the last clustering column being restricted.

> Q2: Single column slice restrictions mean `>, >=, <=, <`?

Direct queries on secondary indices support only =, CONTAINS or CONTAINS KEY restrictions.

> Q3: The indexed columns can be restricted only by =, CONTAINS, and
>   CONTAINS KEY?

CONTAINS and CONTAINS KEY restrictions can only be used on collections when the query is using a secondary index.

> Q4: `CONTAINS` can be used on any non-indexed clustering column? Buy
>   when one column is secondary indexed, `CONTAINS` can only be used on
>   this column when this column is `collections` type?

Regular columns can be restricted by =, >, >=, <= and <, CONTAINS or CONTAINS KEY restrictions if the query is a secondary index query.
IN restrictions are not supported.

> Q5: What does `Regular columns` mean? Always `Single column slice
>   restrictions are allowed only on the last clustering column being
>   restricted.`. If one column is secondary indexed, `=, >, >=, <= and <,
>   CONTAINS or CONTAINS KEY restrictions (but not IN)` can be restricted
>   on this column, even if it is not last clustering column?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Secondary index is all the example where they use 'CREATE INDEX'.

Q2: Yes, all of those inequality operators produce a slice of the query.

Q3: Yes, essentially CONTAINS will look inside a collection and look for that particular item. It only works if the column has a secondary index otherwise Cassandra would have to scan every collection to check.

Q4/5: Questions are a bit confusing. Regular columns in this context will be non-partition key columns.

Comment: As for Q1, `Secondary index queries` means queries on the table where index exists or queries on the column which indexed?